# Mixing Owin Asp.Net Identity Cookie Authentication with Owin OpenId Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

Does anyone know a good example of mixing Owin Asp.Net Identity Cookie Authentication (local db) with Owin OpenId Authentication (cloud)? Users could then choose to login/register with either creating new user&pass (stored in local database) or via e.g. Office 365 account. But all users will use the claims and roles in the asp.net Identity (local database).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this, but I have some weird issues. Here is my ConfigureAuth method in Startup.Auth.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

         app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        //app.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Security.Constants.DefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType"] = "ExternalCookie";

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
          //  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
          new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
          {
              ClientId = clientId,
              Authority = authority,
              PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
          });
    }
```

Logoff method in AccountController

```
   public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        //AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut( 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        );
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

Here is the issue, I tried to explain on another thread which hasn't got any response yet.

[Link for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006822/is-it-possible-to-have-both-azure-ad-and-individual-account-authentication-in-on)