# Is it possible to have both Azure AD and Individual Account authentication in one ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure

I am kind of successful by doing this in the Startup.Auth.cs file

```
  // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Security.Constants.DefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType"] = "ExternalCookie";

        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
             Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
          new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
          {
              ClientId = clientId,
              Authority = authority,
              PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
          });
```

The challenge I have is, when a user is signed out,and tries to hit a non-login page like say http://mywebsite/users/management rather than http://mywebsite/account/login the application redirects to the Azure AD sign-in page automatically, which is not right. Because there could be users who do not have account on Azure AD at all. Even if we give a proper userid and password in the AD sign in page and click sign-in, it keeps redirecting between different urls within http://login.windows.net and never goes to our website at all.

Here is the logout code -

```
           AuthenticationManager.SignOut(new string[] { DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType });
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**Edit 1**
My ExternalLoginCallback method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "Office365"));

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login

        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Name);

        if (user != null && user.IsActive == true && user.EmailConfirmed == true)
        {
            var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (claims != null)
                {
                    var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
                    userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                }
            }

            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
            Session[AppConstants.General.UserID] = user.Id;

            string fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}",user.FirstName,user.LastName);
            Session[AppConstants.General.UserFullName] = fullName;

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, tell that to the user.
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
           new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
           {
               ClientId = ClientId,
               Authority = Authority,                   
               Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
               {


                   RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                   {

                       if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/Account/ExternalLogin" || (context.Request.Path.Value == "/Account/LogOff" && context.Request.User.Identity.IsExternalUser()))
                       {
                           // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                           // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                           // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                           string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                           context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                           context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           //This is to avoid being redirected to the microsoft login page when deep linking and not logged in 
                           context.State = Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications.NotificationResultState.Skipped;
                           context.HandleResponse();
                       }
                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   },
               }
           });
```

EDIT:

Forgot this extension method

```
    public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static bool IsExternalUser(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (ci != null && ci.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var value = ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Sid);
            if (value != null && value == "Office365")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

You have to have some custom logic in the ExternalLoginCallback (AccountController) e.g. add the Sid claim. In this case there is also logic to check if the user allows external login.

```
 // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl, string urlHash)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "Office365"));

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(loginInfo.DefaultUserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if(user.AllowExternalLogin == false)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User {0} not allowed to authenticate with Office 365.", loginInfo.DefaultUserName));
                    return View("Login");
                }
                var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (claims != null)
                    {
                        var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
                        userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                    }
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                }
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User {0} not found.", loginInfo.DefaultUserName));
                return View("Login");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            if (user.AllowExternalLogin == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User {0} not allowed to authenticate with Office 365.", loginInfo.DefaultUserName));
                return View("Login");
            }

            if (claims != null)
            {
                var userIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager);
                userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
            }
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but for me the variable "value" is null when an external user logs in. Is this because of my other app.UseCookieAuthentication() setting? Basically, I replaced my app. UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() with yours and kept the rest there. Is it right?

Comment: You are right. Check out the EDIT 2 in the answere. You can certainly simplify the ExternalLoginCallback function if you want

Comment: Tried that, but I get null on this line -
`code` var value = ci.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Sid);

Comment: can you post your implementation of ExternalLoginCallback ?

Comment: It does get hit right? Have you tried to debug the method?

Comment: It hits the method. No problem at all. But the value is null.

Comment: Yes, debugging hits the code. No issue in that. I have posted my ExternalLoginCallback method. Please see EDIT 1 in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73442/discussion-between-imaya-kumar-and-kjartan-valur-ordarson).

Comment: have you made any progress? Did you not find this helpful?

Comment: The only issue was not using the right SignIn method. After I changed to SignInManager.SignInAsync() things started working well.

Comment: @ImayaKumar  I'm trying to do almost similar process. however after Azure AD login, page keeps reloading between /Account/ExternalLogin and microsoft Azure login

Comment: @KjartanValurÞórðarson in Edit 1 i am not able to get claim `var value = ci.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Sid);` when i checked the claims collection, i cannot find this `ClaimTypes.Sid, "Office365"` in the collection. Can you help me with this. :)

Comment: @KjartanValurÞórðarson After struggling for 3 hours, i solved it by adding claims in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager)` method only. Well i later found out that when this `await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);` line of code is executed. Then, `GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager)` method is called again and it again adds the claims.

Comment: Hi,  When the If part under RedirectToIdentityProvider will execute?