# Limitation of Azure Websites Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I am applying azure active directory authentication to my website, which is shown as below.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/#

Now the above reference link shows that earlier there was a limitation like ("With the current release the whole site is placed behind login the requirement.")

In my application, i want some pages as a public facing (that should not require azure active directory login)

So i want to know that is the above limitation is still there and if not, then how do i achieve this?

Please help me on this

Comment: this was already answered. See thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006822/is-it-possible-to-have-both-azure-ad-and-individual-account-authentication-in-on

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the opportunity to try it recently, but my current understanding is that the limitation is still there and that when you use this feature the whole site is placed behind login the requirement ( Even if Byron Tardif speaks of a possible feature next to come in one of his answers in the article you have referred to : "Not right now, but we have this in our backlog of things we want to enable").
So the solution would be, as Byron suggests (for a public API) either to have two web sites : one private or one public.

Another solution would be not to use this feature and implement yourself the non systematic authorization logic between your web app and AAD. You have many ways to do it depending the stack you're using (NET, PHP, Node, Java or Python) and it will require more effort to have it work.

Hope this helps
Happy new year !
Stéphane

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your answer. I think i have to use another method to achieve this.