# Supporting both Individual Accounts and Work or School Account based on directory

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, razor-pages

I'm building an ASP.NET Core Razor website (version 2.2).  There are basically two areas of the website: an administration area for the owners of the website and a customer facing area.  The directory structure has all the customer facing pages under the "Pages" folder and all administration pages under a subfolder called "Admin".

I would like to use work or school account authentication (single tenant) for all pages under the "Admin" folder.  This will allow administrators to use their Azure AD accounts for login for managing the website.  For all other pages, I want to use the Individual user accounts authentication with a local data store.

I presently have the Azure AD authentication working, but is it possible to specify the two different authentication mechanisms based on directory where Pages under "Admin" will use Azure AD while all other pages will use Individual Accounts)?

There is a similar post where others have indicated an answer but that was over 4 years ago and didn't use ASP.NET Core so please don't close this by pointing to that article. ([Is it possible to have both Azure AD and Individual Account authentication in one ASP.NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006822/is-it-possible-to-have-both-azure-ad-and-individual-account-authentication-in-on))

Currently I just have the AzureAD code in place.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: It is as simple as validating the logged in user role against each Action. You can keep Admin pages have fallen under one role and other pages in other role and validate that from B2C returned claims. You can show up pages based on the logged in user role.

Comment: B2C custom policies support for both Individual accounts and work/ school accounts.

Comment: Are you asking about Azure AD or Azure AD B2C? You don't mention B2C in the question.

Comment: I'm using local store for individual user accounts so no B2C in this equation.  Just trying to understand how to wire up the authentication for both types based on directory.